# How to find a function (GET, POST, ... ) by index.js with an Express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, react-router

I would like to install a router in Express. I followed a good tutorial but my code still don't find my function get/users.

My function works when I put it on index.js

index.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const users = require('./api/user');
app.use('/users', users);
```

./api/user.js :

```
const {user, validate} = require('../models/user');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql')

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'mf_consultation' 
});

router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Enter in get request");
    const queryString = "SELECT * FROM user"
    connection.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if(error) return res.status(400).send(result.error.details[0].message);
        console.log("I think we fetched users successfully");
        res.json(rows);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have this result on postman

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /users</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

My console didn't display the console.log "Enter in get request".

Have you an idea ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you have specified `/users` as the common path for user router, your get request should be to `/users/users`. If you want that path to be `/users`, change `router.get('/users')` to `router.get('/')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index.js`, you have specified this:

```
app.use('/users', users);
```

This means that any route that starts with `/users` should be handled inside your `users` router.

Then, in your `users.js`, you have this:

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  // code here
}
```

This means that your express application will handle `/users/users` instead of just `/users`. The first `/users` leads your express application to use your `user` router, while the second `/users` leads your `user` router to use the `GET` function defined inside the router.

If you want to reach the controller/handler with only `/users`, there are 2 ways:

1. define this in your `index.js`

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  // code here
});
```

2. replace your `router.get('/users', ...` with `router.get('/', ...` in your user router.

Both ways should work, just that the structure of your code base will change a little.